# A non well formed numeric value encountered php

Tags: php

I am passing date from the database and set the value of dateforService, then I send the URL value to the other php file to update the db. But everytime I try to save in the db, it is saved as 0000-00-00.

Here are the codes below :

```
echo "<td><input type= 'text' name = 'jobrequestnumber' value =".$row['jobrequestnumber']."></td>"  ; // results in the same jobrequestnumbers
echo "<td><input type= 'text' name = 'requestingcompany' value =".$row['requestingcompany']."></td>"    ;//this too
echo "<td><input type= 'date' name = 'dateforService' value =".$row['dateforService']."></td>"  ;// this one also 
echo "<td><a href=\"update_request.php?jobrequestnumber={$row['jobrequestnumber']}&requestingcompany={$row['requestingcompany']}&dateforService={$row['dateforService']}\">Update</a></td>";
```

So I tried to echo the value right before the update codes below:
then It comes out with the correct date format.

```
if (empty($errors)){
$jobrequestnumber = $_GET['jobrequestnumber'];
$requestingcompany = $_GET['requestingcompany'];
$dateforService = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_GET['dateforService']));
    $query =    "UPDATE jobrequest SET 
                        requestingcompany = '{$requestingcompany}',
                        dateforService = $dateforService 
                    WHERE jobrequestnumber ={$jobrequestnumber}";
```

I appreciate your pieces of advice, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Validate inputs from GET before passing them to your query! Currently it's wide open for SQL injection attacks. What gives you `var_dump($dateForService);` ?

Comment: dateforService = $dateforService should be 'dateforService = '$dateforService' need the "'" around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
dateforService = $dateforService
```

with

```
dateforService = '$dateforService'
```

and just in case

Replace

```
jobrequestnumber ='$jobrequestnumber' // remove { & }. You are not using an array here. And add quotes around it
```

Comment: You do know that single quotes represent the *literal* value?

Comment: Yes ofcourse @FreshPrinceOfSO, but the whole statement is put inside double quotes (") right?

Comment: My mistake, you're right. In this case though, the OP needs to use prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks. but why do we need to replace date value to quoted value?      isn't it regarded as string not date value ?