# PHP Error: "A non-numeric value encountered in..."

Tags: error-handling, wordpress-theming

I recently changed my PHP version from 7.0 to 7.1 on my server. In reviewing my error logs, I am now getting the following error:

> AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /width.php on line 74\nPHP

The code that is affected is below. Line 74 is the very last line in the code, which is reproduced below.

```
//
// Get settings.
//

$a = x_get_option( 'x_layout_site' );
$b = x_get_option( 'x_layout_content' );
$c = x_get_option( 'x_layout_site_width' );
$d = x_get_option( 'x_layout_site_max_width' );
$e = x_get_option( 'x_layout_content_width' );
$f = x_get_option( 'x_layout_sidebar_width' );


//
// Adjust settings.
//

$site_layout    = ( $a == '' ) ? 'full-width'      : $a;
$content_layout = ( $b == '' ) ? 'content-sidebar' : $b;
$site_width     = ( $c == '' ) ? 88 / 100          : $c / 100;
$site_max_width = ( $d == '' ) ? 1200              : $d;
$content_width  = ( $e == '' ) ? 72 - $m           : $e - $m; // Line affected
```

I have read about the non well formed numeric value encountered error discussed in the following places.[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014612/a-non-well-formed-numeric-value-encountered-using-maths-functions-in-cakephp3),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079104/a-non-well-formed-numeric-value-encountered-can-not-reproduce),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002031/php-a-non-well-formed-numeric-value-encountered),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857946/a-non-well-formed-numeric-value-encountered-php) Doing a few Google searches, it seems that this is related to the way that PHP 7.1 deals with non-numeric calculations, as referenced here.[5](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1272) The recommendation is trapping a potential 'auto' value in the $content-width and converting it to zero. I have tried to do such error trapping with the following code changes:

```
//
// Adjust settings.
//

$site_layout    = ( $a == '' ) ? 'full-width'      : $a;
$content_layout = ( $b == '' ) ? 'content-sidebar' : $b;
$site_width     = ( $c == '' ) ? 88 / 100          : $c / 100;
$site_max_width = ( $d == '' ) ? 1200              : $d;
if ($m=='auto') {$m=0;} // set auto to 0
$content_width  = ( $e == '' ) ? 72 - $m           : $e - $m; // Line affected
```

However, the error seems to continue. The other suggestion that was made was to suppress PHP Warnings, but as I am in the process of debugging other code, I do not want to do that. I also do not think that is good practice.

For anyone who is interested in where the larger code body comes from, it is the 'X' theme for WordPress. The error occurs only here when converting from PHP 7.0 to 7.1.

Appreciate any insight into getting this fixed. Thanks.

Comment: I have the exact same error. Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually fixed it by upgrading to the new X theme update and updating to PHP 7.1.8. No more error!